# How can I assign the name of the current wifi network to a variable in windows batch scripting?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, netsh, wifi

I am trying to add a line to my start up scrip which would automatically start the VPN if I am connected to WiFi networks outside of my work.

I can get the names from *netsh wlan* commands, but I am not able to just "pick" the SSID/network name from that.

Is there a way to extract particular information from the *netsh* output or is there a way to output just the wifi name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `findstr` command to find a string in a commands, specifically the SSID.

**Script:**

```
@echo off
set "wifiNetwork=example network"

(netsh wlan show networks | findstr /C:": %wifiNetwork%" >nul 2>&1)&&goto :found

echo Wi-Fi network "%wifiNetwork%" not found
goto :end

:found
echo Wi-Fi network "%wifiNetwork%" found!

:end
pause
```

*NOTE: The findstr command is case-sensitive unless you add the `/I` option*

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind telling me what this part does?  
  
`findstr /C:": %wifiNetwork%" >nul 2>&1)`  
  

Ah you got rid of the "if" part I was planning on using by using the goto. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @NVAR The `findstr` command searches the output of the `netsh wlan` for the network name - `%wifiNetwork%`. If it finds it, then `goto :found`